# Windows 2008 r2 & WIndows 7 file replication

Tags: windows-7, sync, windows-server-2008, file-server, replication

Does Windows 2008 r2 offer a way to replicate files (sync) between a Windows 7 Client Computer?
The Window 2008 R2 Server and Windows 7 computer are on two different subnets and are networked via VPN.  I do know about Branch Cache Is Branch Cache the only way between a Windows Server and Windows Client? Or is file replication controlled by Windows 2008 R2 possible with a Windows 7 Pro client?

Only things I can find are 3rd party programs and DRFS but thats between 2 Windows 2008 Servers.

Answer (score 0):

See about RSync, it is tried and true (old faithful) and works on different OS's. There is a frontend you can also use called DeltaCopy for ease of deployment. http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp

Comment: I would think the problem would be, if User A had File 1 open on the Main Office File Server and User B had File 1 on Windows 7 computer that was same file but synced between the offices, that User B could OVERWRITE User A's Data If User A had it opened at same time! I guess I need more than just Sync. I need to make sure that if File 1 in Main Offce that is being synced with with File 1 in Branch Office, that something is telling the person if File 1 is open. Thus I would think DRFS still wins, but I can't set it up between Windows 2008 R2 and Windows 7 :(

Comment: I have not tested that - but then i tend to tell it to rsync late at night...